# Как удалить рандомно созданные кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt, qpushbutton

В окне есть блок кнопок с рандомными названиями. 
При нажатии на кнопку **`"Х"`** нужно удалить только эти кнопки, а все остальные кнопки и элементы формы должны остаться на экране.

Логика подсказывает, что кнопки, которые надо удалить, нужно объединить через общий идентификатор, а потом удалять кнопки, у которых на форме этот идентификатор установлен. 
Вот только как это сделать я не могу понять.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Пример")
        buttons = [str(random.randint(0,100)), str(random.randint(0,100)), str(random.randint(0,100)), str(random.randint(0,100))]
        x = 10
        y = 0
        # Блок кнопок, которые надо удалить по нажатию на кнопку "Х"
        for button in buttons:
            y = y + 25
            btn = QPushButton(button,  self)
            btn.move(x, y)
            btn.setToolTip(button)
            btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())

        # Кнопки, которые должны остаться после нажатия на "Х"
        btn = QPushButton("Эта кнопка должна остаться", self)
        btn.move(100, 40)
        btn = QPushButton("И эта кнопка должна остаться", self)
        btn.move(100, 80)

        btn = QPushButton("Х",  self)
        btn.move(100, 10)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.delete)

    def delete(self):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', "Вы действительно хотите удалить?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        print("Да" if reply == QMessageBox.Yes else "Нет")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

На экране появляется окно и в нем, при нажатии на **`Х`**, нужно удалить только кнопки с рандомными названиями (в моем примере, это случайные числа), а все остальное оставить на месте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример") 
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)                                        # !!!  
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                                 # !!!        

        self.addButtons()                                                         # +++
        
        # Кнопки, которые должны остаться после нажатия на "Х"
        btn = QPushButton("Эта кнопка должна остаться", self.centralWidget)
        btn.move(100, 40)
        btn = QPushButton("И эта кнопка должна остаться", self.centralWidget)
        btn.move(100, 80)

        self.btn_add_delete = QPushButton("Delete",  self.centralWidget)          # self.centralWidget
        self.btn_add_delete.move(100, 10)
        self.btn_add_delete.clicked.connect(self.deleteButtons)
        
    def addButtons(self):
        self.buttons = [
            QPushButton(str(random.randint(0,100))), 
            QPushButton(str(random.randint(0,100))), 
            QPushButton(str(random.randint(0,100))), 
            QPushButton(str(random.randint(0,100)))
        ]
        x = 10
        y = 0
        #Блок кнопок, которые надо удалить по нажатию на кнопку "Delete"
        for button in self.buttons:
            y = y + 25
            btn = button
            btn.setParent(self.centralWidget)
            btn.move(x, y)
            btn.setToolTip(button.text())
            btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())    
            btn.show()

    def deleteButtons(self):
        if self.btn_add_delete.text() == "Delete":
            reply = QMessageBox.question(
                self, 
                'Message', "Вы действительно хотите удалить?", 
                QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, 
                QMessageBox.No
            )
            if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
                print("Да <<-----")
                for button in self.buttons:
                    button.hide()
                self.btn_add_delete.setText("Add")        
        elif self.btn_add_delete.text() == "Add":
            self.addButtons()
            self.btn_add_delete.setText("Delete")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```py
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Пример")
        # -----------------------------
        button_names = [str(random.randint(0,100)), str(random.randint(0,100)), str(random.randint(0,100)), str(random.randint(0,100))]
        self.buttons = []
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        x = 10
        y = 0
        #Блок кнопок, которые надо удалить по нажатию на кнопку "Х"
        for name in button_names:    # <-----
            y = y + 25
            btn = QPushButton(name,  self)
            btn.move(x, y)
            btn.setToolTip(name)
            btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
            self.buttons.append(btn) # <-----
        
        # Кнопки, которые должны остаться после нажатия на "Х"
        btn = QPushButton("Эта кнопка должна остаться", self)
        btn.move(100, 40)
        btn = QPushButton("И эта кнопка должна остаться", self)
        btn.move(100, 80)

        btn = QPushButton("Х",  self)
        btn.move(100, 10)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.delete)

    def delete(self):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', "Вы действительно хотите удалить?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        print("Да" if reply == QMessageBox.Yes else "Нет")
        # --------------------------
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            for btn in self.buttons:
                btn.hide()
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @PetrSklyarov думаю, нет